# How would I merged nested dictionaries in a list in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, addition

for example if i had the result

```
[{'Germany': {"Luge - Men's Singles": 'Gold'}}, 
{'Germany': {"Luge - Men's Singles": 'Silver'}},
{'Italy': {"Luge - Men's Singles": 'Bronze'}}]
[{'Germany': {"Luge - Women's Singles": 'Gold'}},
{'Austria': {"Luge - Women's Singles": 'Silver'}},
{'Germany': {"Luge - Women's Singles": 'Bronze'}}]
[{'Austria': {'Luge - Doubles': 'Gold'}}, 
{'Latvia': {'Luge - Doubles': 'Silver'}},
{'Germany': {'Luge - Doubles': 'Bronze'}}]
```

how would I sort this so that all of the events germany and so on had won could be under one single title. 
i.e germany would be germany:Luge - Men's Singles: Gold, Silver, Luge - Women's Singles: Gold, Bronze, Luge - Doubles: Bronze.

thanks for any help

EDIT: this is a straight copy and paste from the python shell now to help confusion:

[{'Germany': {"Luge - Men's Singles": 'Gold'}}, {'Germany': {"Luge - Men's Singles": 'Silver'}}, {'Italy': {"Luge - Men's Singles": 'Bronze'}}]
[{'Germany': {"Luge - Women's Singles": 'Gold'}}, {'Austria': {"Luge - Women's Singles": 'Silver'}}, {'Germany': {"Luge - Women's Singles": 'Bronze'}}]
[{'Austria': {'Luge - Doubles': 'Gold'}}, {'Latvia': {'Luge - Doubles': 'Silver'}}, {'Germany': {'Luge - Doubles': 'Bronze'}}]

sorry about that im new to this site. It loops round 3 time one for each different event and i was wondering if i could get the desired from merging it after the final loop?

Comment: I've expanded my answer, I think it does what you want now. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Sorry, I really meant this as a comment on Alex Martelli's answer, since mine is based on his; but when I originally posted I didn't have enough reputation to comment)

Alex's answer doesn't actually generate the intended result. I don't mean the finer points of having a list of lists of dicts, or the lack of commas between the lists (more on that later). But the original question wanted, as a result, a compilation of all medals by country, *by competition*. Alex's solution will answer:

```
> 'Germany': [{"Luge - Men's Singles": 'Gold'},
             {"Luge - Men's Singles": 'Silver'},
             {"Luge - Women's Singles": 'Gold'},
             {"Luge - Women's Singles": 'Bronze'},
             {'Luge - Doubles': 'Bronze'}]
```

But I believe the original question actually asked for:

```
> 'Germany': [{"Luge - Men's Singles": ['Gold', 'Silver']},
             {"Luge - Women's Singles": ['Gold', 'Bronze'},
             {'Luge - Doubles': 'Bronze'}]
```

The data in the question is a bit confusing, I see two possibilities:

1) The data shown is actually *three* different examples, and the task is to merge dict entries within each list, separately. That is, given

```
[{'Germany': {"Luge - Men's Singles": 'Gold'}}, 
{'Germany': {"Luge - Men's Singles": 'Silver'}},
{'Italy': {"Luge - Men's Singles": 'Bronze'}}]
```

you want

```
['Germany': {"Luge - Men's Singles": ['Gold', 'Silver'],
             "Luge - Women's Singles": ['Gold', 'Bronze']},
 'Italy': {"Luge - Men's Singles": ['Bronze']}]
```

, given

```
[{'Germany': {"Luge - Women's Singles": 'Gold'}},
{'Austria': {"Luge - Women's Singles": 'Silver'}},
{'Germany': {"Luge - Women's Singles": 'Bronze'}}]
```

you want

```
['Germany': {"Luge - Women's Singles": ['Gold', 'Bronze']},
 'Austria': {"Luge - Women's Singles": ['Silver']}]
```

and so on. I gather this is the most likely interpretation of the question.

The following code does that:

```
from collections import defaultdict

merged = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for d in list_of_dicts:
    for k in d:
        for competition, medal in d[k].iteritems():
            merged[k][competition].append(medal)
```

Running this for the first of the lists shown above, you get

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x1907db0>,
 {'Italy': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {"Luge - Men's Singles": ['Bronze']}),
  'Germany': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {"Luge - Men's Singles": ['Gold', 'Silver']})})
```

2) The second possibility is that the data in the question is one single list, containing 3 lists, each of these containing dicts. I think this is not what the original question means, but, since I'd already written the code for that, here it is :)

```
from collections import defaultdict

merged = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for L in listoflistsofdicts:
  for d in L:
    for k in d:
      for competition, medal in d[k].iteritems():
          merged[k][competition].append(medal)
```

Running the code above for the lists shown on the question (with the necessary commas added, you get:

```
 defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x1904b70>,
    {'Italy': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {"Luge - Men's Singles": ['Bronze']}),
     'Austria': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Luge - Doubles': ['Gold'],
                                            "Luge - Women's Singles": ['Silver']}),
     'Latvia': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Luge - Doubles': ['Silver']}),
     'Germany': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Luge - Doubles': ['Bronze'],
                                            "Luge - Men's Singles": ['Gold', 'Silver'],
                                            "Luge - Women's Singles": ['Gold', 'Bronze']})
    })
```

Please note that both of these codes don't sort medal types (i.e., you might end up with ['Gold', 'Silver'] or ['Silver', 'Gold']).

Of course, if you get separated lists as used in solution 1), but need a merge of all of them, simply bring them all together in a list, and use solution 2).

Comment: thanks for the update it worked out for me in the end. think this is the answer im going to use. ill make it correct when i figure out how.

Answer (score 4):

```
import collections

merged_result = collections.defaultdict(list)

for L in listoflistsofdicts:
  for d in L:
    for k in d:
      merged_result[k].append(d[k])
```

or if you just have a list of dicts instead of a list of lists of dicts (hard to say from your Q!-), then just the

```
  for d in listofdicts:
    for k in d:
      merged_result[k].append(d[k])
```

part of the loop.

If you want strings rather than lists as the values of `merged_result` then after the above code add

```
for k in merged_result:
    merged_result[k] = ', '.join(merged_result[k])
```

or, equivalently (but building a new plain dict instead of the defaultdict):

```
merged_result = dict((k, ', '.join(v)) for k, v in merged_result.iteritems())
```

(this assumes Python 2.* -- in Python 3, use `.items` instead of `.iteritems`).

**Edit**: looking at the sample code it looks like it's invalid syntax for a list of list of dicts (missing commas) so I showed how to deal with that, too.

Comment: Hah, we have an interpret-off. Which one of us interpreted the question correctly! :)

Comment: On second viewing, it's obvious you were interpreting it correctly ;P

Comment: @Thomas, still not obvious to me, but, we'll see (one hopes;-).